# Thermal Heat Transfer

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity

I work for a large plant bakery and we have recently coated the inside steel walls of our very large oven with a reflective coating. I have taken temperature readings inside the insulation void and there is a noticeable decrease.

What I am trying to do is quantify the theoretical energy savings in LPG usage from this.
It's been quite some years since I ever tried to calculate anything like this and I am in dire need of some guidance. Is Fourier's Law the right direction to be taking with this?

E.G $\dfrac{Q}{T}= \dfrac{KA(T1-T2)}{D}$

$=\text{Thermal conductivity of oven wall} \times \text{surface area of walls}\left(\frac{\text{temp before painting-temp after painting}}{\text{thickness of wall}}\right)$.

Some more background information:
Heat is generated from an LPG burner located centrally in the oven. It is a large swing tray style oven measuring $6$ meters wide by $25$ meters. The reflective coating is a silver heat stable paint on the inside of the oven, before this they were black with carbon. The oven has $2$ steel layers with insulation in between them - temperature readings were taken from inside the insulating cavity.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi. Your formula is *a bit of that* and *a bit of this* but it's not really Fourier. I think your problem needs a bit more information, like some numbers, a bit of info on the reflective coating, where did you measure that temperature, where and how is the heat generated?

Comment: Heat is generated from an LPG burner located centrally in the oven. It is a large swing tray style oven measuring 6 meters wide by 25meters. The reflective coating is a silver heat stable paint on the inside of the oven, before this they were black with carbon. The oven has 3 steel layers with insulation inbetween them - temperature readings were taken from inside the insulating layer.

Comment: I've voted to close but only to prompt you to provide more info, as requested above. If you do I will formulate an answer.

Comment: Hi Gert, I have replied to your previous comment, I hope that's enough detail.

Comment: Thank you. I'm working on it. It'll be a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this problem all three modes of heat transfer occur:

1. radiative
2. conductive
3. convective

Firstly, we assume the furnace operates in steady state, so that all heat generated by the LPG burner dissipates away through the furnace's wall. In that case, **all temperatures are constant in time**.

Also I'll approximate the furnace by a single wall with surface area $A$ and thickness $\Delta x$.

We can write, for steady state:

$$Q_{in}=Q_{out}$$
Now we distinguish $3$ zones, I, II and III:

[image: Wall temperature]

Left of the $T$-axis is the heat source ($Q$), right the wall with surface area $A$ and thickness $\Delta x$.

1. **Radiative zone (zone I):**

Inside the furnace we consider all heat to be radiative and with [Stefan-Boltzmann Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law#Effective_temperature_of_the_Earth):

$$Q=A\epsilon \sigma T_1^4\tag{1}$$

Here $\epsilon$ is the emissivity, close to $1$ for a perfect black body, lower for grey bodies.

> The reflective coating is a silver heat stable paint on the inside of
>   the oven, before this they were black with carbon.

You've basically reduced $\epsilon$ considerably and this will also lower $T_1$ (which is basically what you found)

Note that in zone I some heat convective transfer may also occur, so that:

$$Q=A\epsilon \sigma T_1^4+h_1A(T_f-T_1)$$

where $h_1$ is the inner convection heat transfer coefficient and $T_f$ the furnace temperature (far away from the walls)

But in the radiative zone (I) it is assumed that:

$$\epsilon \sigma T_1^4 \gg h_1(T_f-T_1)$$

2. **Conductive zone (zone II):**

Using Fourier we can calculate the amount of heat conducting through the wall with thickness $\Delta x$:

$$Q=kA\frac{\text{d}T}{\text{d}x}=kA\frac{T_1-T_2}{\Delta x}\tag{2}$$

where $k$ is the thermal conductivity of the insulating material.

3. **Convective zone (zone III):**

Finally the right side of the wall still loses heat to the environment, which it at temperature $T_{\infty}$. We can use Newton's Law of Cooling to calculate it:

$$Q=hA(T_2-T_{\infty})\tag{3}$$

where $h$ is the convection heat transfer coefficient.

**Overall heat balance-**

With $(1)$, $(2)$ and $(3)$ we can write:

$$Q=A\epsilon \sigma T_1^4=kA\frac{T_1-T_2}{\Delta x}=hA(T_2-T_{\infty})$$

I hope the above has provided you with some insights into the various mechanisms of heat transfer in play here. But it should also make clear that any calculation will be made difficult by uncertainty on $k$ and $h$, as well as difficulty measuring the various temperatures.

To calculate energy savings it is probably easier and more accurate to rely on observational data of LPG consumption, before and after the change of reflective coating.